# functionally combine list of same object

Tags: java, kotlin, functional-programming, set

I have a set of alerts that I need to combine and output. I'm struggling to see how I can do this functionally. I have everything I need I just want to combine format a little and output.

orderedStatuses contains a set of alerts

```
data class Alert(
    val status: String,
    val recordId: String
)
```

This is what I'm currently returning

```
  Alerts:
        Status1 : 
          000000000000
        Status1 : 
          111111111111
        Status2 : 
         222222222222
        Status2 : 
         333333333333
        Status3 : 
         444444444444
        Status3 : 
          555555555555
```

this is what I want:

```
Alerts:
    status1 : 
    ('00000', '111111')
    status2 : 
    ('222222', '333333')
    status3 : 
    ('444444', '55555')
```

current code:

```
val alert = if (orderedStatuses.isEmpty()) {
    "No alerts found for status"
} else {
    "Records:\n" + orderedStatuses.joinToString("\n") { it ->
        "\t${it.status} : \n" + it.recordId

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what is `('00000', '111111')` in the output? Is it supposed to be `recordId`?

Comment: yes you are correct @viv3k

Comment: `val recordIdsByStatus: Map<String, List<String>> = orderedStatuses.groupBy(Alert::status).mapValues { (_, alerts) -> alerts.map(Alert::recordId) }`

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Can you add the value for `orderedStatuses `. Making very crude assumptions, is this what you are looking for https://pl.kotl.in/VSuhOLGMP ?

Answer (score 1):

```
data class Alert(
  val status: String,
  val recordId: String
)

val alerts = listOf(
  Alert("Status1", "00000"),
  Alert("Status1", "111111"),
  Alert("Status2", "222222"),
  Alert("Status2", "333333"),
  Alert("Status3", "444444"),
  Alert("Status3", "55555")
)

alerts
  .groupBy { it.status }
  .map { map -> map.key + " : \n('" + map.value.joinToString("', '") { it.recordId } + "')\n" }
  .forEach { print(it) }
```

This will print:

```
Status1 : 
('00000', '111111')
Status2 : 
('222222', '333333')
Status3 : 
('444444', '55555')
```

This might be more readable:

```
alerts
  .groupBy(Alert::status)
  .map { (key, value) -> 
    key + " : \n('" + value.joinToString("', '", transform = Alert::recordId) + "')\n"
  }
  .forEach(::print)
```

[Detailed example on Kotlin Playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)

Comment: This worked but can you go into a few details on what's happening in the .Map you wrote.

Comment: @AnthonyEdwardsStan ``groupBy`` returns a ``Map`` where the keys are the elements you're grouping by (the statuses) and the values are the items in each group (as a ``List``). What might be confusing is that this is followed up with a ``map`` call, which transforms each element in the collection (i.e each ``Map.Entry``) , and lukas is calling each entry ``map`` in the transform function. Imagine it's called ``group`` in the function instead

Comment: @AnthonyEdwardsStan Added a detailed example on Kotlin Playground (see link at the bottom of my answer), which shows all the lambdas used as explicit functions.